# `r.row` and `r.contains ` in nested queries not working

Tags: rethinkdb

Trying to add a new field inside of a document using a field from another table. I first tried to use r.row

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter({name:'Andre Pastr'}).update({teacher_name: r.db('teacher').table('basic_info').contains(r.row('name').eq('Nicholas Derma')).pluck('id')});
```

and it returned the message:

```
e: Cannot use r.row in nested queries.  Use functions instead in:
r.db("client").table("basic_info").filter({name: 'Andre Pastr'}).update({"teacher_name": r.db("teacher").table("basic_info").contains(r.row("name").eq("Nicholas Derma")).pluck("id")})
                                                                                                        ^^^^^
```

so then after finding this [vague entry][1] in the github issue log I just decided to just change the syntax of my query and run:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter({name:'Andre Albuquerque'}).update({teacher_name: r.db('teacher').table('basic_info').filter({name: 'Nicholas Chadwick'}).pluck('id')});
```

That returned the error message:

```
: Could not prove argument deterministic.  Maybe you want to use the non_atomic flag?
```

Three inter-related questions: How might I use contains to run such a query? What am I doing wrong with this second query? Why doesn't r.row work in the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `r.row` in the first query because it's ambiguous whether it should be bound to `contains` or to `update`.  (We could define which one it's bound to, but it's very confusing for people because most people haven't memorized all the terms that could possibly bind `r.row`, so it's easier to force people to name their variables in ambiguous cases.)

You have to specify the `non_atomic` flag because the function you're passing to update can't be applied atomically (since it isn't deterministic).  The way you wrote it, it will be executing a table fetch for every row in the original filter.

You probably want to write something like this instead:

```
r.table('basic_info').filter({name: 'Nicholas Derma'}).pluck('id').do(function(nderma) {
  return r.table('basic_info').filter({name: 'Andre Pastr'}).update({teacher_name: nderma);
})
```

You should consider creating a secondary index on `name` and using `getAll` instead of `filter` if you run this query often.

Comment: Nice answer. The explanation about why my original solution didn't work is super helpful for those of us still learning. Many thanks!

Comment: @mlucy Is `getAll` faster than `filter` because it doesn't need to support multiple keys? Or does `filter` not support indexes?